# What makes records immutable?

Tags: moqui

I was loading the Mantle data and I get the error below saying that the record is create-only (immutable). I don't think it will affect me, but I thought it might be something worth answering.

```
Loading entity data from [file:/home/byersa/dev/moqui-on/runtime/mantle/mantle-udm/data/ZzcProductDemoData.xml]
--- 195489   [main] WARN  moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl
 Transaction rollback. The rollback was originally caused by: Error loading entity data org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error storing entity [mantle.product.asset.AssetDetail] value: org.moqui.entity.EntityException: Entity [mantle.product.asset.AssetDetail] is create-only (immutable), cannot be updated. org.moqui.entity.EntityException: Entity [mantle.product.asset.AssetDetail] is create-only (immutable), cannot be updated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a setting on an entity using the entity.@create-only attribute (set to true).

You are seeing this error during a data load because the data is loaded into a database with data already in place (i.e. a second data load without cleaning out the DB).

The AssetDetail (part of Mantle Business Artifacts) is set to create-only as it is a running history entity and records should only be created, not updated/etc.